# Accessing a single XML DOM Document node

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

I am completely new to DOM Documents, basically what I am trying to do, is to load a RSS feed in and select only one node, and then save it to a XML file.

Here is the XML I am loading from a web feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Markets</title>
        <description/>
        <link>http://www.website.com</link>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <copyright>XML Output Copyright</copyright>
        <ttl>15</ttl>
        <pubDate>Tue, 16 Nov 2010 09:38:00 +0000</pubDate>
        <webMaster>admin@website.com</webMaster>
        <image>
            <title>title</title>
            <url>http://www.website.com/images/xmllogo.gif</url>
            <link>http://www.website.com</link>
            <width>144</width>
            <height>16</height>
        </image>


            <item>
                <title>title</title>
                <description>the description goes here
                </description>
                <enclosure url="http://www.website.com/images/image.png" type="image/png"/>

            </item>

    </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is my lame attempt at getting the `<description>` node and saving it to feed.xml:

```
<?php  

    $feed = new DOMDocument();
    $feed->load('http://www.website.com/directory/directory/cz.c');
    $nodeValue = $feed->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $feed->save("feed.xml");

?>
```

So basically I need to get the description tag, and save it as a XML file.

Any help would be appreciated, thanx in advance!

Comment: please clarify whether you want to save the **node** or the **node's value**. These terms cannot be used synonymously when working with DOM Trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost correct. To get the "outerXml" of a node, you can pass the node to `saveXml()`

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load('http://www.website.com/directory/directory/cz.c');
$xml = $feed->saveXml($feed->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0));
file_put_contents("feed.xml", $xml);
```

Saving with `file_put_contents` will not include an XML prolog. Note that in your example, the first description element is empty, so the file will contain `<description/>`.

If you want to extract the node as standalone XML Document, you have to instantiate a new `DOMDocument` and [import](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) the `DOMNode` and then use `save()`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument($feed->xmlVersion, $feed->xmlEncoding);
$dom->appendChild(
    $dom->importNode(
        $feed->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0),
        TRUE
    )
);
echo $dom->save('new.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');
$descr=$feed->channel->description;
```

Try this